# extJs Button image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, image, google-chrome, extjs

It seems that Chrome is becomming the new IE when it comes to CSS ~~`

I have following code for creating extjs buttons in an acordion:

```
                var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    text: '<img src="'+resp.sellers.external[key].catalogs[0].logo+'">',
                    handler: function() {
                        openOciCall(resp.sellers.external[key].catalogs[0].catId, me.queryFilterManager.getValue())
                    },

                    margin: '3 3 0 3',

                });
```

Now in FF and IE all looks great like here:

[image]

But in Chrome without the height property it looks like crap:

[image]

And to make it worse when i add the Height  property i end up with this:

```
                var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    text: '<img src="'+resp.sellers.external[key].catalogs[0].logo+'">',
                    handler: function() {
                        openOciCall(resp.sellers.external[key].catalogs[0].catId, me.queryFilterManager.getValue())
                    },

                    height: 55,
                    margin: '3 3 0 3',

                });
```

Which gets me this:

[image]

The problem is that ExtJs is generating a padding value in Chrome, which screws the image...

```
<span id="button-1128-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on" style="line-height: normal; padding-top: 27px;"><img src="logos/logo_mercateo.png"></span>
```

Now my question is, is there a better aproach to get the image to be show like here in firefox?

[image]

EDIT:

When i try to make it via the icon element i get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better method to display the image on your button would be to use the appropriate `icon` parameters available for the [Button class](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.button.Button.html) :

```
 var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    text: ' ',
                    iconCls:'btImage',
                    handler: function() {
                        openOciCall(resp.sellers.external[key].catalogs[0].catId, me.queryFilterManager.getValue())
                    }   
                    ...

                });
```

Necessary CSS:

```
btImage {
background-image: url(/images/logo.png) !important;
}
```

**Note:I have not tested the code.. but you can play with icon,iconCls,iconAlign params to achieve what you need**

Comment: The problem is that the image is a dyamical variable which gets pulled from a variable from the resp.sellers.external[key].catalogs[0].logo

Comment: use the icon param then.. you can provide the path to an image to display in the button .. ExtJS will set it a background image for the css

Comment: Tried that already, but it shows only a litle square of the image. I added descr. in question